# displaying a list of files

Tags: php, mysql, database, directory

In my web application I have the user sign up for an account, then the account data is saved in a mysql database. The user can then go to "index.php" and log in with their credentials. My application involves saving a file to a directory. So:

1. User logs in.
2. A table is displayed. The table contains a list of files saved in the directory that is for the individual user.
3. The user uploads a file to their directory (by directory I mean like a folder).

How could I display the files in a folder in a table () using php?

thanks!

Comment: PHP Manual says: opendir() http://uk.php.net/manual/en/function.opendir.php; scandir() http://uk.php.net/manual/en/function.scandir.php; glob() http://uk.php.net/manual/en/function.glob.php

Comment: Tried migrating this to StackOverflow but it was automatically rejected. I don't know why.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`glob()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.glob.php) to loop through the directory and get the list of files in it.

```
<?php
foreach (glob("*.*") as $filename) {
  if (is_file($filename)) {
    echo "$filename size " . filesize($filename) . "\n";
  }
}
?>
```